Can't use environment variables in React when using NX
I'm using NX for management of my monorepo which houses a React app and a NestJS app.
The NestJS app can read the environment variables locally and deployed. The React app however is always showing undefined.
I have read the documentation for NX which hasn't seemed to help me work this out.
My structure is:
/nx-monorepo
  /apps
    /react-app
      /src
        /environments
          environment.ts
          environment.prod.ts
      .env
      ...
      webpack.config.js
    /nest-app
      /src
      .env
  nx.json
  package.json

If I log the environment variables in the webpack config, these show up correctly at build time.
webpack.config.js
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/webpack');
const { withReact } = require('@nx/react');

module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), withReact(), (config) => {        
  console.log('Environment Variables:')
  console.log('NX_FLYOUT_SERVICE_URL: ', process.env.NX_FLYOUT_SERVICE_URL);
  console.log('NX_IS_PRE_RELEASE: ', process.env.NX_IS_PRE_RELEASE);
  console.log('NX_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ', process.env.NX_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY);

  return config;
});

I use NX's environment files to leverage the replacement of these files during build time.
environment.ts
type Environment = {
  production: boolean;
  flyoutServiceUrl: string | undefined;
  isPreRelease: boolean;
}

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  flyoutServiceUrl: process.env.NX_FLYOUT_SERVICE_URL,
  isPreRelease: process.env.NX_IS_PRE_RELEASE === 'true'
};

When I try to log either the environment or process.env within the react app, the variables are not correct. process.env gives me an empty object, whereas environment gives me the {production: false, flyoutServiceUrl: undefined, isPreRelease: false}. I uderstand both of these results if the variables are not working properly.
app.tsx
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export const App = () => {
  console.log(environment);
  console.log(process.env);

  return <AppMain />
};

Is my setup wrong or am I missing something for the environment variables to be readable within the React app?

I am facing the same issue.
Did you solve it?
